# Where is VR1 on the Game Boy Advance schematics?

Tags: schematics

You can find the GBA schematics [here](https://console5.com/techwiki/images/7/76/GBA-Schematic-CPU.png).
On the center bottom part there is VR2.
I am quite sure this is the volume wheel.
But I am a little confused it says VR2 because the device only has one potentiometer. So where is VR1? I also cannot find it on the schematics.

Comment: While you did get an answer, this is probably a question better suited for retrocomputing.SE.

Comment: @Hearth I think this is not directly a retrocomputing.SE question. The only link to retrocomputing is that the question is about schematics of an old portable handheld gaming device, instead of about schematics of an old portable tape player. After you said that it better suits retrocomputing, there is a "can the GBA volume pot be replaced with slightly different pot" on retrocomputing.SE which is more a general electronics question.

Answer (score 3):

VR1 is northeast from VR2.

It connects to U5 pin 4, Q3 collector, and LCD connector P2 pin 29 called VCOM.

By the looks of it, it's the contrast pot.

Comment: The GBA has no contrast pot. (I got a GBA here.) I am a little confused. So why is there one on the schematics?

Comment: @somega Just because there's no *user accessible* contrast pot doesn't mean there isn't one used for factory adjustment. I'd even go so far as to say that the majority of potentiometers in devices are not user-accessible, only used for factory adjustment of various things and then locked in place with some kind of sealant goo.

Comment: @somega There is. Right in the schematics, and you can see it on a PCB if you find a photo of the PCB. Some people access it by poking a hole in the label sticker.